# How to solve e libc error on Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions, android-9.0-pie

I have a oneplus 6 and 5 and when I do HTTP requests, using volley is always showing this:

```
    2018-12-18 15:28:59.941 900-1404/? E/OnePlusSmartBoostManager: socket connect
2018-12-18 15:28:59.941 900-1404/? E/OnePlusSmartBoostManager: cmd: iop_start 21345 com.example.andre.aplicacaocalibracaov4 /data/app/com.example.andre.aplicacaocalibracaov4-J7o6Z4HHWkuvTAl4cUHrDA== false length = 136
2018-12-18 15:28:59.941 900-1404/? E/OnePlusSmartBoostManager: data: [B@8e973ab length = 136
2018-12-18 15:28:59.941 931-21379/? E/ANDR-RAMBOOST_SERVER: ramboost cmd_len = 136 cmd: iop_start 21345 com.example.andre.aplicacaocalibracaov4 /data/app/com.example.andre.aplicacaocalibracaov4-J7o6Z4HHWkuvTAl4cUHrDA== false
2018-12-18 15:28:59.941 931-21379/? E/ANDR-RAMBOOST_SERVER: io prefetch Capture is deactivated 
2018-12-18 15:28:59.952 21345-21374/com.example.andre.aplicacaocalibracaov4 E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
2018-12-18 15:29:00.447 21345-21374/com.example.andre.aplicacaocalibracaov4 E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
2018-12-18 15:29:00.946 21345-21374/com.example.andre.aplicacaocalibracaov4 E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
2018-12-18 15:29:01.450 21345-21374/com.example.andre.aplicacaocalibracaov4 E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
2018-12-18 15:29:01.951 21345-21374/com.example.andre.aplicacaocalibracaov4 E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
2018-12-18 15:29:02.451 21345-21374/com.example.andre.aplicacaocalibracaov4 E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
2018-12-18 15:29:02.952 21345-21374/com.example.andre.aplicacaocalibracaov4 E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
2018-12-18 15:29:03.454 21345-21374/com.example.andre.aplicacaocalibracaov4 E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
2018-12-18 15:29:03.955 21345-21374/com.example.andre.aplicacaocalibracaov4 E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
2018-12-18 15:29:04.456 21345-21374/com.example.andre.aplicacaocalibracaov4 E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
```

I tried everything this days and I can't do anything to that. This is an Android P problem!

Comment: have you any solution?

Comment: I think this problem related only to oneplus devices.